# Testing a function inside a function with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, function, jasmine, spyon

I have a function that has a function inside it I need to be able to test that the inner function gets called I'v tryed looking for examples of spyOn but not quite found anything I could us the code im trying to test is like

```
function OutterFunc(){
    function InnerFunc(){
        return "A";
    }
    var b = InnerFunc();
    return b;
}
```

The test i wish i could do is that InnerFunc has been called
Any help would be really really welcome

Comment: Can't you move the inner function out of the outer function? If it closes over any local variables you can just pass those in as arguments... once the function is accessible to the 'outside world' you should be able to use `spyOn`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I don't see any way obvious way of testing whether that inner function was called. In the trivial case you give above, I suppose getting a return value of "A" is pretty compelling proof that the function was called.

If testing to make sure a function was called in a certain way, under certain conditions you'd have to refactor your code.  You could move the inner function out of the other one as in the comment above. You might pass the inner function into the outer one like so:

```
var inner = function(){
    return 'A';
} 

function OuterFunc(fn) {
    return fn();
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
var res = OuterFunc(inner);
```

Now you can spy on inner.  There are other possibilities, but you are going to have to do some refactoring to get that inner function tested.

Comment: That what i thought but i had to ask the question thanks

Comment: If you don't mind, could you mark the question as answered as well :-)

Comment: I was hoping another one would come with this is how to do it but ye i think your way is the only way so i will